# Can I stop GCE Enforcer from deleting VPC Rules?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, vpc

I am working on a project that is jointly owned by Google, and I like to use RDP to work in a familiar desktop testing environment.

So I create VPC rules to allow RDP ports, and it works, but "gceenforcer@system.gserviceaccount.com" deletes the rule every few hours, which is quite annoying.

Is there a way to whitelist specific rules with GCE Enforcer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Google-owned projects have firewall rules automatically manipulated by GCE Enforcer, though there are some rules that are added to allow connectivity from [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) IP spaces.

the options might be:

- tunneling `RDP` through another port (in case any should be permitted).
- tunneling through a bastion host, which not belongs to a Google owned project.